# Recylerview appends the old result on back pressed

Tags: android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to create a application with bottom navigation view, But it looks like it is stacking up the fragments. Let me show you the picture to be clear.[image: this is image 1 when app opens]

[image: from home I went to other page and when I clicked back button this happened it showed 2 results of same]

[![Blank screen when back button is clicked again][3]][3]

Here is the code:
Home.xml

```
 <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomfrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center">
        <com.rawat.soccermatch.CustomBottomNav
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/enable_disable"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/enable_disable"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior" />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF9800"
        android:contentDescription="@string/title_create"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plusn"
        app:tint="#fff"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Home.java

```
        bt = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    loadFragment(new HomeFrag()); // at first home fragment will be loaded
    bt.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment mfragment;
            int item_id=item.getItemId();
                    if(item_id==R.id.navigation_home){
                        mfragment = new HomeFrag();
                        loadFragment(mfragment);
                    }
                    else if(item_id==R.id.navigation_feed){

                        mfragment = new Feed();
                        loadFragment(mfragment);
                    }
                    else if(item_id==R.id.navigation_create){

                        mfragment = new creatematch();
                        loadFragment(mfragment);
                    }
                    else if (item_id==R.id.navigation_following){

                        mfragment = new Following();
                        loadFragment(mfragment);
                    }
                    else {

                        mfragment = new Account();
                        loadFragment(mfragment);
                    }

            return true;
        }
    });

    ft = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    ft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ft.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
            ft.setRippleColor(Color.GREEN);
            Fragment fragment = new creatematch();
            bt.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_create).setChecked(true);
            loadFragment(fragment);
        }
    });

}

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.bottomfrag, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Should I post HomFrag Code too?

[image: picture 2]

I have edited the question now the problem which I understand is when clicking back my Home Fragment is resuming from where it was left but the recylerview values are resetting and appends the new results with old. Also the ripple color is not changing from following to home.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this function instead of yours

```
 public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    try {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.replace(R.id.bottomfrag, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem of blank screen but still can't get rid of double values I have edited the question please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding that fragment to backstack so when you click back detach it, you need to make sure that your fragment is not added to backstack

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem of blank screen but still can't get rid of double values I have edited the question please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed() method. Inside it you can check what section is opened at the current moment and what you want to do in this case (nothing/close the app/navigate to another section).

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem of blank screen but still can't get rid of double values I have edited the question please take a look.

Comment: I can't see the code, but i suppose, that you add the date in onResume() method, so when you back on the screen, it's add it once again. Solution - move this code to onCreate() or onCreateView() method.

Answer (score 0):

in the bottom navigation activity you have to set default fragment is select which fragment you want for eg in common Home fragment always show as a default fragment so set homefragment as default.

set these code on create

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
```

checkon backpress

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            finish();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem of blank screen but still can't get rid of double values I have edited the question please take a look.